# python win32com bulk reading outlook emails - too many open items

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server, win32com, mapi

i'm facing some issues while trying to fetch a bulk mail via python wincom32.client.

Basically, it seems like there's a limit on the number of items that could be opened on a single session, and that is a server-side flag or status..
the problem is that i didn't find out any way to resume/close/re-set and i can't ask for sysadmins to do it for me..

Here's my code snippet - i know it's ugly - but i'm using it on a jupiter notebook just to experiment/play around before arranging it down properly.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

def create_message_list(folder):
    return [{
        "folder": folder.Name,
        "sender" : m.Sender,
        "recipients" : m.Recipients,
        "subject" : m.subject, 
        "body":m.body
        } for m in folder.Items]

for folder in outlook.Folders:
    if (folder.Name=="myfolder.name"):
        message_list = create_message_list(folder)
```

and here's what i get:

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft
>   Outlook', 'Your server administrator has limited the number of items
>   you can open simultaneously. Try closing messages you have opened or
>   removing attachments and images from unsent messages you are
>   composing.', None, 0, -2147220731), None).

Notice that i *had my sketch code working for a while*. i could fetch something like 10k messages before it messed up with that error.

Things i've been trying (with no result)
 - try to close the folder / mapi session
 - running a for loop on the same items and calling the message.Close(0)
 - using the GetFirst() / GetLast() methods on message instead of list comprehension

thanks anyone for ideas/suggestions/whatever.

Comment: What is your code processing the items? One thing to keep in mind is that you should avoid using "foreach" loop as they keep all enumerated items open until the loop exits.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko the only processing i'm doing is collecting the items fields as shown - i wanted to store the whole list in a pandas dataframe to perfom further operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was due to using dictionary to store message data held somehow a reference to it, without letting the resource to be released, even if an explicit `m.Close(0)` was invoked.

I've replaced them all with a `"dictkey" : str(m.<field>)` call and the error does not show up anymore.

Comment: According to https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-September/012546.html, `<message>._oleobj_` contains a PyIDispatch object which is not tracked by the garbage collector.

Comment: @Equinox23, would you mind sharing a sample snippet of your code please. I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @RaviKiranGururaja desolate, but it was a 4-years old issue..since then, i've left the company i was, and honestly i don't even remember the details..moreover, i do not have neither the code nor the data anymore, of course. i'm sorry..hope my own (old) answer can be somehow helpful.

Comment: @Equinox23 no worries. Your answer has been quite useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks Equinox23 for your answer.

Just wanted to add few more points to it. The same thing happened for me while accessing bundles of outlook emails. Consider `list1` and `list2`, for every iteration I get the output `list1` and finally, append it to `list2` and reset the list1. After 230+ iterations, I got the same error. Here, the `list2` has reference for `list1` as Equinox23 mentioned and doesn't allow us to open multiple items at a time.

So, instead of directly appending `list1` to `list2` (like `list2.append(list1)`), I did the following as Equinox23 mentioned (`list2.append(str(list1))`) [Use the appropriate datatype like `str(list1)/int(list1)` and append it].

You can eliminate the error and can get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You keep *all* items in a folder open - that is a really bad idea. Store only the entry ids, and reopen the messages on demand using `Namespace.GetItemFromID`. As soon as you are done with the item, release it.

Comment: thank you, but as you can read in my own answer, i've found the real cause.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko , how do we retrive entry ids. Is it possible to share any sample code please?

Comment: Read `MailItem.EntryID` property